# iOS Facebook SDK: FBSDKGraphRequest doesn't return email (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've seen similar questions on here but none seem to resolve my issue.

I'm currently creating an iOS app that uses the Facebook SDK to login and return user information.

I've successfully logged into facebook and receive the requested information. However, the request is not returning email despite allowing read permission for email.

```
    /********************
    Place Facebook login button
    *********************/
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.delegate = self
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]
    //add button constraints
    loginButton.center = view.center



}

/**
* Functions called when user handed back from facebook login
**/
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("Did log out of facebook")
}
/**
 * Functions called when user handed back from facebook login
 **/
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else
    {
        print("Successfully logged in with facebook")
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start
            { (connection, result, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("Failed to start graph request: ", err)
                return
            }
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Email is only returned if the user has confirmed and verified it already. Plus there are some rare situations in which privacy settings make it not return the email, even if the user granted the permission. If your app absolutely _needs_ an email, then you should implement an additional step to let users input it manually (of course verification becomes your responsibility too then) ... not every user even has an email on file with Facebook, for example if they registered using only their mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Well i pondered on this for a long time and came upon [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail&version=v3.2) which suggested that if you don't have a confirmed email address I won't get it back in the login section of my code.

```
let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"], accessToken: AccessToken.current, httpMethod: .GET, apiVersion: "2.12")
                request.start { (response, result) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        print(value.dictionaryValue!)
                        self.responseJSON = JSON(value.dictionaryValue!)
                        let fullName = self.responseJSON["first_name"].stringValue
                        let firstName = self.responseJSON["first_name"].stringValue
                        let lastName = self.responseJSON["last_name"].stringValue
                        let email = self.responseJSON["email"].stringValue
                        let idFb = self.responseJSON["id"].stringValue
                        let picture = self.responseJSON["picture"]["data"]["url"].stringValue

                        print("user id: \(idFb), firstName: \(firstName), fullname: \(fullName), lastname: \(lastName), picture: \(picture), email: \(email)")

                    print("ALL FIELDS PUBLISHED")


                    if let delegate = self.responseDelegate {
                        delegate.responseUpdated(self.responseJSON, forLogin: "FB")
                    }

                case .failed(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

Hence when I got to it and confirmed my email address it gave me the email in response. Here are some attached snapshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is how i got to it. Later I implemented that if the email is not returned, I showed an alert alerting the user that there is no email associated with that facebook account and either they confirm their email or proceed by giving a separate email address in an TextField Alert. And thats that.

Comment: Follow your instructions, same issue for me, I was struggling for 2,3 hours, +1

Comment: @AbuzarManzoor happy i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch the users email from an FBSDKGraphRequest according to [Facebook Graph API tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dabout%2Cemail&version=v2.9). Facebook only returns the token used to login. If you used Facebook login with Firebase you could fetch the email with CurrentUser.currentEmail Method.

```
 let login = FBSDKLoginManager()

    login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","user_posts","public_profile"], from: self, handler: {
        (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Process error")
            return
        }
        else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Cancelled")
        }
        else {
            //Success!
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            self.firebaseLogin(credential)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I see that Firebase does not store any email address when user signs up. I'll find a way around this. Thanks again

Comment: Right, in Swift 2 and the older Firebase + Facebook SDKs the method above was allowed but now you can just write 'FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email'

Answer (score 0):

```
 import FBSDKCoreKit
        import FBSDKLoginKit
        import FBSDKShareKit


      @IBAction func btnFbPressed(_ sender: Any) {

            let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

            loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (loginResult, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)

                }
                else {

                    if (loginResult?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))! {
                        self.getFBUserData()
                    }

                }
            }


        }




        func getFBUserData(){
            if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){

                UserDefaults.standard.set(FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString, forKey: "fbToken")

                FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {

                        print(result as Any)

                        let dictionary = result as! NSDictionary
                        print(dictionary)

                        let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
                        hud.tintColor = .black
                        hud.mode = .indeterminate
                        hud.label.text = "Loading"
                        hud.animationType = .fade
                        hud.show(animated: true)

                        let postString = String(format: "login_type=facebook&email=%@&id=%@&device=0", arguments: [dictionary.value(forKey: "email") as! String, dictionary.value(forKey: "id") as! String])
     }
                })
            }
        }
```